# Selected Dropdownlist vaue is not updating in the UI Knockout js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, knockout.js

In my application, I am using a drop down list as shown below.

```
<select id="ddlcurrency" data-bind="options: $root.ddlOppCurrency, optionsText: 'CurrencyCode', optionsValue: 'CurrencyCode', optionsCaption: 'Select..', value: selectedCurrId, valueUpdate: 'change'" class="form-control"></select>
```

I am having a div in which the selected dropdown value has to be binded.

```
<div class="col-md-8 value" data-bind="text: (CurrencyID() == '' || CurrencyID() == null || CurrencyID() == undefined) ? '--' : CurrencyID">
```

I have created a function to bind dropdown list and a function to bind the selected value as shown below.

```
function ddlOppCurrency(CurrencyCode)
{
    this.CurrencyCode = ko.observable(CurrencyCode);
}

function Config(CurrencyID) 
{
   this.selectedCurrId = ko.observable(CurrencyID);
}
```

Now, when I change the dropdown list, the selected value is not updating in UI. Can anyone let me know how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/74dh736s/24/ . something different you looking for please feel free to fork the fiddle and let me know  cheers . .

Comment: Thanks fpr your Reply. My dropdown list will be binded when a row is selected from table. So I have created a method to load the drop down separately and binded the selected value in another method. I tried your 'subscribe' choice. but that too didn't reflect in UI.

Comment: any errors in console ? can you try like this `this.selectedCurrId=ko.observable() & inside function this.selectedCurrId(CurrencyID)` instead of doing like `this.selectedCurrId=ko.observable(CurrencyID)` .

Comment: This too didnt work for me.. I have used a set of properties to bind view and another set of properties (with same name) to send the updated value.. is this may be the issue that iam not getting the desired result???

Comment: well its hard to keep guessing try reproducing your issue in fiddle . `with same name` yes viewModel and view bindings should share same prop's and when you update you should update the same prop's . do a back track anywhere on initial load you trying to assign `CurrencyID` like this `self.CurrencyID="value"` instead of doing `self.CurrencyID("value")` . cheers